# Bundled .NET application on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, mono, windows-xp, mkbundle

I know that Windows XP is out of support for a long time now, but we still have customers using machines that they cannot update to a more recent OS.

We now want to write a new application and while there's always the option to go with a statically compiled C++ application, I would like to use C#.

I think that it may be possible to use an older version of Mono together with mkbundle to create such a self-contained application.

I cannot find real information on the subject, namely the last supported version of mono on Windows XP SP2. According to this thread: https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/1723, Mono 4.0.0 should work, but I also found information that says it's 3.2.3 (https://opensourcepack.blogspot.de/p/xp-last-resort_12.html).

Before we start extensive testing, I would like to know if anybody had a similar situation and has another approach or could find real (official) information on the subject?

**Edit:** We could use the old .NET framework 4.0 which works on XP. But the machines are sometimes very limited in terms of disk space and we cannot always install the .NET framework. This is why I explore other options now.

Thanks,
Knurd

Comment: I can only tell you my experience with C# on Windows XP. I made a simple application with network communication. *(Only a few classes, single simple windows with 1*ComboBox, 3*Buttons, 1*ProgressBar, 1*RichTextBox, and TCP commununication)* I compiled it for .NET Framework 2 (in Visual Studio 2015). The application woks fine on Win7, Win8, Windows Server *(not my PC, unknown version)*. But at Windows XP (with .NET) there was a "Application Crashed" window after short time (up to 2 minutes). But the application did not stop when you did not press anything on the "crash window".

Comment: Why are you worried about finding a supported version of Mono, when the OS it will be running on has not been supported for years? Pick a version of the .NET Framework that worked on XP when it was last supported, compile for that, and you should be fine - logically if it worked when XP was in support it will work while it is out of support...

Comment: @RB. Sure - supported is maybe the wrong term. I mean the last working version. You are right, we should use the old .NET framework 4.0 - I am investigating the other options, because the machines are very limited in terms of disk space and it may be possible that we cannot install the .NET framework.